# A question about Lebesgue-Stielties measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset R$.

($A_{\mu}$ is the domain of the Lebesgue-stielties measure $\mu$ ($A_{\mu}$ is a sigma-algebra that contains the borel sigma algebra).

A. Prove that if $E=H\cup N$ where H is a countable union of closed sets and $\mu(N)=0$ then $E\in A_{\mu}$.

B. prove that if $E\in A_{\mu}$ and $\mu(E) < \infty$, then $E=H\cup N$ where H is a countable union of closed sets and $\mu(N)=0$.

My try:

A.

$H\subset B_{R}\in A_{\sigma}$.
$N\in A_{\mu}$ as $\mu(N)=0$, so $E=H\cup N\in A_{\mu}$ as an union of two sets in $A_{\mu}$.

B.

$\forall n\in N$ there's $K_n\subset E\subset R$  such that $\mu(E)\leq \mu(K_n)+\frac{1}{n}$.

Notice that since $K_n$ is compact in $R$ so by a theory in topology ee get that it's closed and bounded.
So, lets define $H=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} K_n$ so H is a countable union of closed sets. And $H\subset B_R\in A_{\mu}$.
Now, let's look at $E\setminus H$.
since $K_n\subset H$ therfore $E\setminus H\subset E\setminus K_n$.
And $\mu(E\setminus H)\leq \mu(E\setminus K_n)=\mu(E)-\mu(K_n)≤ 1/n$ (notice that $\mu(K_n)$ is finite since $K_n\subset E$). This inequality holds for every $n\in N$, so $\mu(E\H)=0$, and finally define $N=E\setminus H$.
Getting, $N\cup H= (E\setminus H) \cup H= E$.

Can you help in this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is obvious because $H$ is a Borel set and $\mu$ is complete. As for (b) you need to use the fact that $\mu$ is regular, i.e., for $E\in\mathcal{A}_{\mu}$,
\begin{align}
\mu(E)&=\inf\{\mu(O):O\supset E, O\text{ is open}\} \\
&=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, O\text{ is compact}\}.
\end{align}
For each $n\ge 1$, choose a compact set $K_n\subset E$  s.t.
$$
\mu(E)\le \mu(K_n)+n^{-1}.
$$
Let $K=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}K_n\subset E$. It follows that $\mu(K)=\mu(E)<\infty$ and $\mu(E\setminus K)=0$.

Comment: For A,  it is true that  $N\in A_{\mu}$ (directly)?,  what i did in b is not fine? (In ur proof you meant $K_n\subset E$ right?)

Comment: $\mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$-measurable sets and it is complete.

Comment: Yes,  what was a little messy for me not mentioning that $N\in A_\mu$. Is my proof in B fine?

Comment: @Almaa Yes, your proof of (b) is fine.

Comment: i edited the first part in my post,  though I guess I did not use the completeness of the measure..